# Como comprobar correctamente el email y contraseña en la BD

Tags: java, jdbc, sha1

Estoy tratando de mostrar un listado de usuario,se pregunta al usuario cual es su email y contraseña, el usuario introduce su contraseña y esta se encripta, la contraseña encriptada se comprueba si existe, si existe en la base de datos, dice que el resultado es correcto, sino dirá que no es correcto.

He de añadir que en la base de datos la contraseña guardada es el sha1 de Nombre_Apellido

Este es el codigo que he tratado de hacer yo, pero siempre da resultado incorrecto, por lo tanto está fallando al comprobar si el email y la contraseña son correctos?.

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        String email;
        String pass;

        try {
            //se crea la conexion
            Connection conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pruebas", "root","");

            //crear objeto statement
            Statement miStatement = conexion.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            //ejecutamos SQL
            ResultSet user = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");

            System.out.println("*=*=*=*Listado de usuarios*=*=*=*");

            boolean existe = false;

            //recorrer  el resultSet
            while(user.next()) {

                System.out.println("Nombre: "+user.getString("firstname") +", "
                        + "Apellido: "+user.getString("lastname"));
            }

            //preguntar email y contraseña
            System.out.println("Introduzca su email:");
            email = lector.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Introduzca su Contraseña:");
            pass = lector.nextLine();

            while(user.next()) {

                String textoSinEncriptar=user.getString("firstname")+"_"+user.getString("lastname"); 
                String textoEncriptadoConSHA=DigestUtils.sha1Hex(textoSinEncriptar);

                if(email.equals(user.getString("email")) && textoEncriptadoConSHA.equals(user.getString("password"))) {
                    //si la contraseña y el email existen marca como true la variable existe
                    existe = true;
                    //añadimos un break para que salga del bucle cuando encuentre la contraseña y el email
                    break;
                }
            }

            //verifica si la variable existe se encuentra en true

            if(existe) {
                System.out.println("Acceso correcto");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Resultado incorrecto");
            }       
            //cerramos la conexion
            user.close();

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("no se puede conectar, el error es el siguiente:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Para las comprobaciones de password no se trata de ir a la BD , traer la password encryptada , desencriptalar y comprarla con el string, si no coger la password que se ingresa , encryptarla y comprarala con la de la BD. Desencryptar cosas de las bd asi porque asi no es buena idea, lo q esta  seguro dejalo seguro

Comment: ah vale comprendo es decir debo compararla con la contraseña encriptada, es decir que debo encriptar lo que añade el usuario y luego comprobar si encaja con la contraseña ya encriptada de la base de datos?

Comment: Voy a actualizar la pregunta ya que me sigue dando resultado incorrecto

Comment: Estás haciendo `System.out.println("Introduzca su Contraseña:");
            pass = lector.nextLine();` y luego comparas el SHA **del nombre+apellido** con la contraseña??

Comment: si exactamente, ya que el sha generado de la contraseña guardada en la base de datos es Nombre_Apellido

Comment: @joseangel Ya he encontrado el error, estaba en boolean existe =false , no detectaba mi variable y debia de ponerla justo antes de hacer la comprobacion, igualmente muchisimas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error residía al no detectar la variable

> boolean existe = false;

La solución para que el código funcione correctamente ha sido colocarlo justo antes del codigo donde quería comparar el resultado.

```
            //preguntar email y contraseña
            System.out.println("Introduzca su email:");
            email = lector.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Introduzca su Contraseña:");
            pass = lector.nextLine();

            boolean existe = false;

            while(user.next()) {

                String textoSinEncriptar=user.getString("firstname")+"_"+user.getString("lastname"); 
                String textoEncriptadoConSHA=DigestUtils.sha1Hex(textoSinEncriptar);

                if(email.equals(user.getString("email")) && textoEncriptadoConSHA.equals(user.getString("password"))) {
                    //si la contraseña y el email existen marca como true la variable existe
                    existe = true;
                    ...
```

Comment: Bien hecho, tienees que tener cuidado con los flags que se usan para retornar si fue o no satisfactoria la funcionalidad que se pretende porque puedes no actualizar de true a false y que la peticion se haya echo correctamente y en el caso de que otra funciona dependa de que esta haya sido true pues no sera llevada a cabo aunque haya salido bien, ten cuidado con esos flags.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo, lo tendré en cuenta

Answer (score -1):

Suponiendo que ya se ha registrado el usuario y tiene una contraseña encryptada almecenada en la BD,

Los pasos correctos a seguir serian:

1.
  Sistema: Introduzca usuario.
  Usuario: Pepito
2.
 Sistema:Introduza contraseña 'Pepito'
 Usuario: hola

3.
  Consulta a la BD donde nombre usuario es 'Pepito' y la password es encriptar('hola').
Si no es null es que existe el user y ya estaria logeado, si es null es que no existe ningun user con esas credenciales, seun si es null el siguiente paso puede ser:

3.1 Bienvenido Pepito. 
 ó 
 3.2 Lo siento, pero no existe ningun usuario con esas credenciales.Intentalo de nuevo.

Espero que te sirva al menos de guia, suerte

Comment: Hola gracias por tu ayuda, pero debo mostrar por pantalla todos los usuarios y pedir unicamente el email y la contraseña y comprobar si es correcto

Comment: Pues a los pasos que te he indicado añadeel siguiente donde veas conveniente : Sistema: select * from usuarios; y mostrar de los usuaiors imagino que el nombre.